# How to fill iPhone X Simulator's background programmatically without Storyboards

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So I've created a new iOS single view application with no core data, no test and then I deleted Main.storyboard and the launch screen storyboard.
I want to do as much in code as I can so I can understand what I'm doing (since I'm just learning iOS programming). The thing is, that I just cant fill the whole iPhone X screen with a background image. I've tried this first using storyboards and had no problem whatsoever. Am I missing something?

```
// AppDelegate.swift

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let mainController = MainController()

        window?.rootViewController = mainController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
}


// MainController.swift

import UIKit

class MainController: UIViewController {
    let background: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bg"))
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()
}

extension MainController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupBackground()
    }
}

extension MainController {
    func setupBackground() {
        view.addSubview(background)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            background.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            background.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            background.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            background.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: you just need to set proper splash screen on iPhone X.

Comment: There, code instead of images (:. Sorry about that

Comment: @brielov, you need to add the splash screen for iPhoneX.

Comment: Without add set splash screen properly not possible

Comment: The simplest approach is to use a launch storyboard. This will automatically resize for all devices and will let iOS know that your app is aware of iPhone X

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok, that worked. Now you said the "simplest approach". What would be a not-so-simple approach if suppose I would like to simply use a splash image from Assets?

Comment: Yes, you can use image files, but then you need to keep adding more images of the right dimensions as new devices are released and you have to create all of those assets

Comment: Oh ok! I understand now. Thanks man you've been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the comments above, you need to **use a launch storyboard** in order for iOS to give you a UIScreen that covers the device's full bounds.

If you don't already have a launch storyboard, create one in Xcode 11 via `File` > `New` > `File...` > `Launch Screen`. Then make sure to select that launch storyboard under your app target > General > Launch Screen File.